# Dynamic ng-init - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, ng-init

I got this:

```
<ul id="filterList">
      <div ng-repeat="data in dataForTheTree">
         <li> {{data.topic}} </li>
          <ul id={{data.topic}}Son>
              <li ng-repeat="d in data.children>  
                 <input type="checkbox" ng-init='{{d.subtopic}}Checkbox = true' ng-checked = "{{d.subtopic}}Checkbox"/>{{d.subtopic}}
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
</ul>
```

I need to create a "model" to know if the checkbox is checked or not (i can not use ng-model because is a bad practice). So, I am trying with ng-checked.
ng-checked will not work if i can not initialise it. I want to try with ng-init because is the only thing that i have read about it.

I have read something about ng-init in a similar post, but i can not understand because I am so new in this world.

"You need to access dynamic properties using [] notation instead on . notation"

How can i do that in this example?

This is my .Json:

```
$scope.dataForTheTree =[
  { "topic" : "Legislation", "children" : [
      { "subtopic" : "Education", "texto" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae tincidunt mi. Donec purus ligula, tincidunt ut semper eu, laoreet.", "children" : [] },
      { "subtopic" : "HealthService", "texto" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae tincidunt mi. Donec purus ligula, tincidunt ut semper eu, laoreet.", "children" : [] },
      { "subtopic" : "Assets", "texto" : " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae tincidunt mi. Donec purus ligula, tincidunt ut semper eu, laoreet.", "children" : [] },
      { "subtopic" : "LiquidAssets", "texto" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae tincidunt mi. Donec purus ligula, tincidunt ut semper eu, laoreet.", "children" : [] },
      { "subtopic" : "Education", "texto" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae tincidunt mi. Donec purus ligula, tincidunt ut semper eu, laoreet.", "children" : [] },
      { "subtopic" : "HealthService", "texto" : " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae tincidunt mi. Donec purus ligula, tincidunt ut semper eu, laoreet.", "children" : [] },
      { "subtopic" : "HealthService", "texto" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae tincidunt mi. Donec purus ligula, tincidunt ut semper eu, laoreet.", "children" : [] }
]}];
```

I want to link each checkbox with his subtopic, then I want to watch if the checkbox is checked through `ng-checked = "{{d.subtopic}}Checkbox"`.

Now my problem is that `"{{d.subtopic}}Checkbox"` is not initialised, and that is why I need to use ng-init.

The problem here is that ng-init does not understand {{}}, so I do not know how to solve this: `'{{d.subtopic}}Checkbox = true'`

Finally I just want to get a dynamic $scope, like for example:

```
var cad = subtopic+"Checkbox";

  if($scope[cad] === true){ [...]
```

Comment: why is using ng-model bad practice?

Comment: I can not use {{d.subtopic}}Checkbox on ng-model, I read something about it. That is better to use ng-checked

Comment: you should use `ng-model="d.subtopic"` why adding the 'Checkbox' ?

Comment: I know it, that was the first thing i tried, but it does not work. Checkbox is like an id, i also have in other side d.subtopicButton and works fine

Comment: oh ok, then you should use `ng-model="d.['subtopicCheckbox']"` if I'm right

Comment: ok, I will try, thanks you

Comment: Anyway i will need to initialise that, how can i do it with ng-init?

Comment: like `ng-init="d.['subtopicCheckbox']=true"` i think

Comment: or maybe you want to use `"Checkbox[d.subtopic]"` i dont understand what model you want to have

Comment: i tried ng-model="d.['subtopicCheckbox']" and it does not work =(

Comment: let me a minute I will redo my question better

Comment: You are using multiple entrys with the same Subtopic, this will cause problems

Comment: I have solved it with a filter for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achive?

```
<ul id="filterList">
  <div ng-repeat="data in dataForTheTree">
    <li> {{data.topic}} </li>
    <ul id="{{data.topic}}Son">
      <li ng-repeat="d in data.children">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-init='d.Checked = true' ng-model="d.Checked" />
        {{d.subtopic}}
        <span ng-if="d.Checked">{{d.texto}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ul>
```

or this?

```
    <li ng-repeat="d in data.children">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-init="$scope[d.subtopic+'Checked'] = true" 
          ng-model="$scope[d.subtopic+'Checked']" />
      {{d.subtopic}}
      <span ng-if="$scope[d.subtopic+'Checked']">{{d.texto}}</span>
    </li>
```

[plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/i8PA5Daa5dVXbDaw4rCa?p=preview)

Comment: I need something like the 2º but without using $scope there, it's like a mix of both. i need d.subtopic.checked as the model, but it does not work.

Comment: then use `"Checkboxes[d.subtopic+'Checked']"` and add `$scope.Checkboxes={};` to your model.

Comment: But then you are suffering because of the same subtopics. So it should be like `"Checkboxes[d.subtopic+$index+'Checked']"` or something similar

Comment: "Checkboxes[d.subtopic+'Checked']"  does not recognized with ng-model neither with ng-init

Comment: @vict you have to add `$scope.Checkboxes={};` to your model or `ng-init="Checkboxes={};"` somewhere outside of the `ng-repeat`

Comment: i did on my controller =S

Comment: @vict, you're welcome! Would you mind accepting my answer then?

Comment: Yes of course if you tell me how hahaha, i am so new here

Comment: @vict click on the tick, below the up- and down-vote arrows, on the left side of this answer.